# how to fill holes in binary image using morphological operators

Tags: matlab

iam new to matlab.I need to represent the image in skeleton form.I used the following code.but i did get skeleton form.

my image is this one:

[image]

I tried this code

```
BW2 = bwmorph(BW,'remove');
figure(7),imshow(BW2)
BW3 = bwmorph(BW,'skel',Inf);
figure(8),imshow(BW3)
```

Comment: can you explain better? what do you want, the skeleton of the image or to fill holes?

Answer (score 0):

Use `BW2= imfill(BW,'holes')` to fill holes in a binary image `BW`.

Edit to address additional points raised:

1) Follow the directions at http://blogs.mathworks.com/steve/2013/09/05/defining-and-filling-holes-on-the-border-of-an-image/ to remove holes that are contacting the edge of the image.

2) I'm not quite sure what you mean about making it a skeleton, but you can trace your region boundaries using `B = bwboundaries(BW)`

Comment: Unfortunatedly is not *that* easy in this case. The big black chunk in the middle of the person wont be filled, as it is not a "hole"

Comment: i nedd to represent that in skeleton form using morpological operators. i used above code .i didnt get exact result.my skeleton image is like this

Comment: i need to represent that image in skeleton form using morpological operators.i already tried for above code.but i didnt get skeleton image.pls help to me sir